# Can anyone suggest procedural snow texture node or dynamic paint appearing on window?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, procedural, dynamic

I'm new when it comes to playing with texture node and dynamic paint. I'm not sure which one is better to make this. I wanted a to make a snow falling and sticking to a window. Like random dots of white appearing on window. I was thinking maybe voronoi for procedural texture, but most of the tutorial is for rain, so i dont know how to make it appear randomly and stay theres, or as the matter infact put colour on them, since all the tutorial shows it being water transparent. I was also thinking maybe using dynamic paint and particle system as brush, but the thing is i need to subdivide the window quite a lot to make it better, which is quite taxing on my computer. Or is it better to use something else? And I'm not looking to make anything photorealistic.

Comment: Hi! Maybe you should just use particle system with plane particles and high stickness setting?

Comment: that did crossed my mind, but like i said, im kinda scared that i might burnt my gpu down lol. but if theres no other option, i might go for that. because there are other things in the scene that makes it heavy already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you need more cheap method rather I've mentioned, you can do someting like that:
[image: Result with Voronoi texture]

You will need just animate `Transmission` parameter with keyframes. You won't get effect that you have discribed, but you'll see something like fogging or misting on your glass. If your camera isn't near that glass you (probably) won't see the difference.

In my opinion, the way with particles can give more interesting result and you can optimise particles with many ways (for example, childrens):
[image: Result with particles]
[image: Result with particles and childrens]